# Unable to Refresh the Excel Connection in Excel Webaccess Webpart

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, business-intelligence, powerpivot

I'm using an excel workbook with pivot in it. I'm using the Excess Webpart to display it. As I click on the Refresh all data connection.

It throws an error. The screen shot is attached.

[image]

I have configured the secure store service and Excel service application. Any Suggestions ??

I have installed SP2010 + SQL Server 2008R2 in server. I have an excel sheet which contains the pivot(the data comes from another SQL server).

I want to show that excel file in Sharepoint. I am using the Excel Web Access Webpart to show it, but on clicking the Refresh All Data connections, it throws an error. Firstly it was gving an error of Delegation. When i configured the Secure Store Service for Excel services, then the error changes to unable to refresh the Data Connection ,contact your system administrator.

Note: I tried to deploy powerpivot solution in SP 2010, but that solution was not found in the Farm Solution().

I 'm installing the Powerpivot(SQL Server) in existing setup.So please can you tell me how to proceed with the above mentioned scenario once when the installation of Powerpivot is complete ?

Can any one suggest anything related to it?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Answered at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38016/unable-to-refresh-the-excel-connection-in-excel-webaccess-webpart

Comment: @josecarlos There is no need to replace "I am" with "I'm". Contractions are optional in English, not required.

Answer (score 1):

find the below URL link on how to Install Power pivot using SP 2010 and SQL Server 2008.
steps are easy to understand and it solves your problem.
[PowerPivot Existing Farm Installation PDF](http://powerpivotgeek.com/docs/PowerPivot_Existing_Farm_Installation.pdf).

cheers,
Ramu

Comment: Thanks @Ramu, I have solved this problem. 
Anyways Thanks but still this document is very helpfull.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I just have to add the Unattended account id in Excel file also. It solved my problem.

Thanks to all.